# Logo looking fuzzy

Tags: fonts, logo, text

I have had a logo design done for me and uploaded to my soon-to-be live website- http://www.samirhussein-starter.com.temp.livebooks.com/ - however on this site is looks fuzzy.
It looks much better on my blog: http://www.samirhusseinblog.com/ . It also looks fine in the finished version they sent to me.
The company who have built my website and designed my logo are not forthcoming about why the logo looks so blurry on this website only.
Any ideas or suggestions?
Thanks!
Sam

Answer (score 5):

The problem is not the logo. It's the fact that the site is built using Flash and with a high degree of compression in the output.

Flash, much as I've enjoyed using it in the past, is (apart from movie trailer sites) just about obsolete as a technology for building websites. It can be finicky, and image quality has to be kept under control. This site doesn't require Flash at all. There's nothing here that couldn't be done more efficiently and no less effectively using modern web technology.

In your situation, given the importance of the material, I would press Livebooks *very* hard on the subject, especially if they have been ignoring the issue thus far. Rather than ask why, just tell them it's entirely unacceptable and must be remedied.

There are times to be quiet and polite, and times to let loose a thunderbolt. This is one of the latter. It's not like you're some unknown High Street photographer from Lesser Puddlewick on Thames.

Comment: I'm rather surprised Livebooks is still around.

Comment: It's good to know the reason for this, thanks very much Alan. I will push Livebooks on this.

Comment: @Sam FWIW, they've been around forever and the fact that they are still Flash based makes me think they're not much for change. So, anyways, just a heads up that it might make sense to shop around for a new portfolio tool that's not flash based.